# device compatible(tablet) but cannot install the app on google play internal testing works fine on phone

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, publish, google-play-console

i am developing a react native app for tablets,

i managed to upload a realease for internal testings, however the app only works on phone but not talblets, the tablet is available on the compatible devices's list, can any one help ? here is my AndroidManifest

```
  package="com.pyProj">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"/>
   
    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:exported="true"
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

my Build.gradle

```
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31
        ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
        androidXCore = "1.7.0"

    }
```

my tablet is a Lenovo TB-X306F

on google play store console i have this in internal testings

```
AppName

Accessible to internal testers
brightness_1
1 release code
Release date: June 6 15:16
Not examined

Version codes
16
Countries/Regions
176
Supported Android devices
17,793
```

the tablet is compatible i can see so i don't really understand why when i share the internal testings link i have this message:

`This item isn't available`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CLOSED This problem was because of country or regional restrictions. account on Tablet is created from another country, i tried changing the email adresse of google play store on the tablet and it worked